# React map function not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update a list, but even though the state is changing the list is not getting rerendered unless I refresh the page. I have not given index as a key yet the list is not getting re-rendered. Any idea why?

js file

```
   function setSpecialty(lang,index){
        var buffarray=types;
        buffarray[index].checked=!buffarray[index].checked;
        setType(buffarray);       
   }
        <View style={[styles.inputviewstyle,{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}]}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:30,fontFamily:"roboto",fontWeight:'bold'}}>Specialty:</Text>
            {types.map((lang,index)=>{
                return(
                    <View key={lang.id} style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'flex-start',width:200,marginLeft:100}}>
                        <CheckBox title={lang.Name} checked={lang.checked}  onPress={() => setSpecialty(lang,index)} />
                    </View>
                ); 
            })}
        </View>
```

Comment: please, provide reproducible sample e.g. codesandbox, or expand your code sample with state manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mutating the same reference, you need to render a copy or the component won't render.you can try this code

```
   function setSpecialty(lang,index){
        var buffarray= [...types];
        buffarray[index].checked=!buffarray[index].checked;
        setType(buffarray);       
   }
```

Or just change to:

```
   function setSpecialty(lang,index){
        var buffarray= types;
        buffarray[index].checked=!buffarray[index].checked;
        setType([...buffarray]);       
   }
```